# DropDown in datagridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, combobox, ssms

hello i have 2 datagridViews in a windows form and i have a combobox in 1 datagridview somwthing like this
[image]

when i change the value of the combobox the tables in the datagridview should be updated.For example if i select the second combobox as outputmetadatafield1 then the columns of that row should be updated with columns of 1st row in output metadata table.by i am not able the add a listener to the combobox as for dropdowns_selectedindexchanged.Can anyone tell m,e how to do that.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        load_input_table();
        load_output_table();
    }
    static String conn = @"Data Source=SUMEET-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=EMIDS;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);

    private void load_input_table()
    {
        String sql = "select * from input_metadata";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
        addcombo();

    }
    private void addcombo()
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn inputtablecombobox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        inputtablecombobox.HeaderText = "field";
        inputtablecombobox.Name = "inputtablecombobox";
        String combosql = "select field from input_metadata";
        SqlDataAdapter comboadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(combosql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        comboadapter.Fill(ds);
        inputtablecombobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        inputtablecombobox.DisplayMember = "field";
        inputtablecombobox.ValueMember = "field";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(inputtablecombobox);
    }
    private void load_output_table()
    {
        String sql = "select * from output_metadata";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
    }
    private void inputtablecombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          MessageBox.Show("text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to show us what you are currently doing?

Comment: Instead of ` combobox.selectedindexchanged` you have to listen to eg DGV.CellValueChanged or some of the various other DGV events..

Comment: @jomsk1e i have put screenshots of what i am doing..when i change the combocell that particular row should be changed

Comment: i mean the code you are using, if you have please show us..

Comment: @jomsk1e i have added the code  inputtablecombobox_SelectedIndexChanged is not triggered when i change the combobox

Comment: @jomsk1e when i select something in the combobox that particular row should be updated.how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you! i found the answer

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        load_input_table();
        load_output_table();
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
    }

    static String conn = @"Data Source=SUMEET-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=EMIDS;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn inputtablecombobox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

    private void load_input_table()
    {
        String sql = "select * from input_metadata";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
        addcombo();

    }

    private void addcombo()
    {
        inputtablecombobox.HeaderText = "field";
        inputtablecombobox.Name = "inputtablecombobox";
        String combosql = "select field from input_metadata";
        SqlDataAdapter comboadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(combosql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        comboadapter.Fill(ds);
        inputtablecombobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        inputtablecombobox.DisplayMember = "field";
        inputtablecombobox.ValueMember = "field";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(inputtablecombobox);
    }

    private void load_output_table()
    {
        String sql = "select * from output_metadata";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
        b.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = b;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(inputtablecombobox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(inputtablecombobox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }
    private void inputtablecombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```